# Build of Dockerfile hangs or taking long?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have this Dockerfile:

```
FROM fedora:28

# create new user
RUN adduser --home /home/rpi-user rpi-user

# install things needed for yocto
RUN dnf -y install make wget bzip2 python unzip perl patch \
     diffstat git cpp gcc gcc-c++ glibc-devel texinfo chrpath \
     ccache perl-Data-Dumper perl-Text-ParseWords perl-Thread-Queue socat \
     findutils which SDL-devel xterm cpio file hostname rpcgen

# run the commands that follow as rpi-user
USER rpi-user

# clone yocto/poky and raspberrypi layer
RUN git clone git://git.yoctoproject.org/poky /home/rpi-user/poky
RUN cd /home/rpi-user/poky; git clone https://github.com/agherzan/meta-raspberrypi.git

# set up oe build environment and add meta-raspberrypi to bblayers.conf
# modify machine name and add options to local.conf
WORKDIR /home/rpi-user/poky
ENV LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 LANG=en_US.UTF-8 LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8
COPY local.conf.append /tmp/
RUN ls -l
RUN . ./oe-init-build-env rpi-build; \
        cd conf; perl -0777 -pi -e 's/(BBLAYERS \?= "Provided more updates.[^"]*)"/\1\/home\/rpi-user\/poky\/meta-raspberrypi \\\n  "/g' bblayers.conf; \
        sed -i 's/\(MACHINE ??= \).*$/\1"raspberrypi3"/g' local.conf; \
        cat /tmp/local.conf.append >> local.conf; \
        cd ../; bitbake -DDDv rpi-basic-image;
RUN echo "[!] Build complete."
```

Doing a `docker build -t bla/rpi .` results in my terminal hanging with (the last 6 lines):

```
NOTE: Running noexec task 3294 of 3294 (/home/rpi-user/poky/meta-raspberrypi/recipes-core/images/rpi-basic-image.bb:do_build)
DEBUG: Teardown for bitbake-worker
DEBUG: Teardown for bitbake-worker
NOTE: Tasks Summary: Attempted 3294 tasks of which 5 didn't need to be rerun and all succeeded.

Summary: There were 5 WARNING messages shown.
```

Running the exact same commands directly on a terminal on the same machine, I am able to build an image without a hang. Only when using docker (and only this specific Dockerfile) does my build hang. I am almost certain it is memory related.

I usually use a script to remove any docker left overs which basically consists of a `docker rmi <images>`, `docker rm <containers>` and `docker system prune --volumes -f`, [here](https://github.com/perplexabot/ckonduej/blob/master/docker_stuff/docker_scripts/remove_all_except.bash) it is if interested. Using said script did not fix my issue (removing of containers, images and volumes did not fix the hang). I then removed `/var/lib/docker` and reset docker daemon, but still no luck.

Any recommendations?

## Update

Looking at `docker stats` while docker was building my Dockerfile, I saw that my cpu usage percentage was constantly over %100 (like in the thousands!). A `dmesg -w` shows messages like this:

```
[ 4409.558822] mce: CPU1: Core temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 3471)
[ 4409.558823] mce: CPU7: Core temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 3471)
[ 4409.558825] mce: CPU0: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 4603)
[ 4409.558826] mce: CPU6: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled (total events = 4603)
```

What is even more interesting is that with `docker stats` running, when the docker build hangs, the entry for that docker/image in `docker stats` goes away, and `dmesg` shows:

```
[ 4701.032315] docker0: port 1(veth0ef04d2) entered disabled state
[ 4701.032481] veth2578e04: renamed from eth0
[ 4701.130810] docker0: port 1(veth0ef04d2) entered disabled state
[ 4701.135113] device veth0ef04d2 left promiscuous mode
[ 4701.135137] docker0: port 1(veth0ef04d2) entered disabled state
```

Which I assume is what I should see upon the exiting of a docker build? Running a `ps aux | grep -i docker`, I still see the process running:

```
<user>    6281  0.9  0.1 1961860 27800 pts/1   Sl+  09:17   0:35 docker -D build -t bam/rpi .
```

So it seems docker thinks the build is done (`docker stats` removes the respective entry) but linux still sees the docker build running (`ps aux` still shows the process). What the?

I am not able to get more "deets" from bitbake, unless there is a flag I am missing. `docker stats` did not show any memory issues as I was expecting.

Wow, apparently a `docker ps -a` shows the container as exited also (in agreement with `docker stats`):

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                      PORTS               NAMES
3ea12a369089        22be583f7349        "/bin/sh -c '. ./oe-…"   About an hour ago   Exited (0) 13 minutes ago                       nifty_gauss
```

I thought it couldn't get more interesting, but it did. In my `ps aux | grep -i docker`, I see an interesting process:

```
root      7775 19.2  1.1 2170612 181216 ?      Sl   10:13   4:04 docker-untar /var/lib/docker/overlay2/f3aade16d0d44ef61037ca5fc7ac0690f66b1894578141add2197fe7f8cdd402/diff
```

What is that? Is it untaring something? That can take a while. Maybe I should wait some more for this hang (I will). This process' `stat` column is constantly changing from `Rl` to `Sl` and back. Weird.

So I waited. The docker-untar process is now gone, but the build is still hanging. Now when I do a `docker ps -a`,  i see this:

```
3ea12a369089        22be583f7349        "/bin/sh -c '. ./oe-…"   2 hours ago         Removal In Progress                           nifty_gauss
```

Interesting, will wait some more.

**The waiting paid off**. The docker image has, rather clumsily, successfully built.

**Why is it taking so long using docker (about x4 longer than running on
the same machine without docker) to build an arm based binary?**

Comment: Try debugging the Dockerfile by commenting out lines until you get to a version that builds. You can then run the image `docker run --intereactive --tty bla/rpi /bin/sh` and attempt the subsequent step(s) until you reach the point where it fails.

Comment: @DazWilkin, thank you. I have actually done that and found that the hang is after `bitbake -DDDv rpi-basic-image` and before `echo "[!] Build complete."` . The `bitbake` command fails at the end of the build process (all tasks are completed).

Comment: Use `docker stats` to monitor the container's resource usage to see if it really memory related...

Comment: I'd be surprised if there's a memory issue. It may be disk related (the local build happens on your host file system; while the build happens on a Docker-managed filesystem). Docker Engine is essentially a process like any other on your host that just so happens to manage namespaces etc. for you. If it builds on the host directly, it should build in a container image on the host.

Comment: See whether `bitbake` can be more verbose in its logging so that you can get more deets on what it's doing. I notice you're building what appears to be a Raspberry Pi binary. Is it possible that you're running an ARM build on an AMD64 host?

Comment: Minor point -- mostly convention -- is to `&&` follow-on commands in a `RUN` statement rather than `;` them. This way the block will fail faster.

Comment: @atline, thanks for `docker stats`, never used. Currently have a docker build running with `docker stats` running, will see what it is upon a hang

Comment: @DazWilkin, interesting that you bring up that it may be disk related. I haven't considered that. Yes, the same commands work on the host (without docker, the yocto build works on the host, I can even boot my rpi with the new image!). I have added another `D` flag to bitbake to see if it has higher levels of debugging, i'll find out soon. Yes, you are correct in that I am running an ARM build on a 64bit host. You know, I have heard of that convention before, I have yet to apply it. You are right, I will use `&&` rather than `;` from now on, thank you.

Comment: I also want to address my first comment where I say "command fails at the end." It does not fail! It hangs!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason my `docker build` was taking much more time than executing the commands on the host directly is because after the `RUN` that executes the `bitbake` command, I am not cleaning up my layer!

As you may know, each `RUN` command is a layer, and each layer is auto-cached by `docker` to make use of later if no changes occurred. That means docker has to tar, remove and cache my layer including all the stuff that was cloned and all the outputs/artifacts of running `bitbake`. So rather than have docker struggle with all this unwanted stuff, I removed it manually:

```
RUN . ./oe-init-build-env rpi-build && \
        cd conf && perl -0777 -pi -e 's/(BBLAYERS \?= "[^"]*)"/\1\/home\/rpi-user\/poky\/meta-raspberrypi \\\n  "/g' bblayers.conf && \
        sed -i 's/\(MACHINE ??= \).*$/\1"raspberrypi3"/g' local.conf && \
        cat /tmp/local.conf.append >> local.conf && \
        cd ../ && bitbake -DDDDvvv rpi-basic-image && mv tmp/deploy /home/rpi-user/ && rm -rf *
```

Note the last two bash commands in this `RUN` (the `mv` and the `rm`).

One could also remove the clones.