# Docker Build Hangs On ---> Running

Tags: docker, containers, dockerfile

newish to docker

I have a docker file that I run docker build on, and it looks like this, where base is an image thats running microsoft/windowsservercore:10.0.14393.2312:

```
FROM base
MAINTAINER Captain Adam Weitzman
SHELL ["powershell", "-Command", "$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue';"]

ENV NPM_VERSION=6.4.1 \
    IONIC_VERSION=3.19.0 \
    CORDOVA_VERSION=9.0.0 \
    NUGET_VERSION=4.7.0;

RUN echo hello world
```

with output:

```
Step 1/5 : FROM base
 ---> 9dbf7f740334
Step 2/5 : MAINTAINER Captain Adam Weitzman
 ---> Using cache
 ---> c8f96e0797b9
Step 3/5 : SHELL ["powershell", "-Command", "$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue';"]
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 769be32b31a5
Step 4/5 : ENV NPM_VERSION=6.4.1     IONIC_VERSION=3.19.0     CORDOVA_VERSION=9.0.0   NUGET_VERSION=4.7.0;
 ---> Using cache
 ---> e2005178d304
Step 5/5 : RUN apt-get update
 ---> Running in 9ddc94cf3765
```

It seems to just hang on the running part, and won't finish building...why? I also have a docker ignore file with ** in it...could that be a reason?

Comment: internet issues?

Comment: my current download speed is 300 mbps so i dont think so

Comment: It would be much easier to help if the Dockerfile was usable on my machine (give a valid base image name). If possible.

Comment: sorry about that, the base image is running an instance of windows server

Comment: btw if i change the last line to "RUN echo hello world" it still hangs

Comment: that base is running microsoft/windowsservercore:10.0.14393.2312 to be specific

Comment: So I ran into something similar. I used `ps aux` and `docker stats` to figure out what is going on. It turned out, in my case, that docker was busy trying to compress, cache, and remove layers. It could be that docker isn't hanging but doing stuff in the background and you just have to wait. Check this if you are interested: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56980332/2923937 . Also, since you are debugging using an echo. Why not try just a `FROM base` followed by your `RUN echo "hello world"` and see if that works? Then introduce layers one by one and see which is the culprit.

Comment: Also to rule out internet issues as @Federkun pointed out, why not add a `RUN ping www.google.com` and see if that works.

Comment: still hangs on the google, whatever i put in run it seems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running parallels needed to devote more memory to my virtual machine